# Embedded icon in single-executable package with PyInstaller 5.12

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm running Python 3.11 and PyInstaller 5.12 on Windows 10. This is my spec file:

```
block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(
    ['myapp.py'],
    pathex=[os.path.abspath(os.curdir)],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=['encodings'],
    hookspath=[],
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False
)

pyz = PYZ(
    a.pure, a.zipped_data,
    cipher=block_cipher
)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='myapp',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    icon='assets/myapp.ico',
    console=False
)
```

I get a nice `dist/myapp.exe` auto-unzipping executable, it works fine, but it has the PyInstaller default icon embedded in the .exe instead of the provided `assets/myapp.ico`.

I don't have this problem with the older version of my app, using Python 3.8 and  PyInstaller 4.2 and *the same spec file*. I don't expect obviously that I don't have to modify the spec file while upgrading to a new major version of PyInstaller but I cannot find in the PyInstaller documentation what's the right why to embed the icon when building the single-exe package.

Where's my mistake? Or it's a bug in PyInstaller 5.12?

Thanks.

Comment: there is no mistake, you must be spelling the file name wrong or be targeting the wrong directory.

Comment: I double checked and it is correct. Also, I tried purposely a wrong file name and PyInstaller fails with a proper error message.

Comment: try install pillow.